# devcon.exe - disable net device failed

Tags: windows, devcon

Windows 7 
devcon can't disable and enable the nic, could you please help me?

```
C:\Users>devcon status =net @PCI\*
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_368217AA&REV_07\07000000684CE00000
Name: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Driver is running.
PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_0032&SUBSYS_311817AA&REV_01\4&1B96513B&0&0015
Name: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
Driver is running.
2 matching device(s) found.

C:\Users>devcon disable PCI\VEN_10EC
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_5229&SUBSYS_522910EC&REV_01\00000001004CE00000: Disable failed
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_368217AA&REV_07\07000000684CE00000: Disable failed
No devices disabled.
```

Comment: downloaded the original `x64` file from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=8A6EBFB5-833D-44E2-BF92-44648A8BB250 (opened as zip), -> support.cab (opened as zip) -> devcon.exe -> still same problem

Answer (score 0):

http://ccm.net/ has an example of how to do this. In that example they are using a '*'. Does it work if you add that to your command?

The following is from http://ccm.net/faq/1886-enable-disable-a-device-from-the-command-line

**Display all the devices in the system**

In the command prompt, type

```
devcon find *> list.txt
```

To get the list in a file
For example, my network card Accton appears as:

```
PCI\VEN_1113&DEV_1211&SUBSYS_12111113&REV_10\3&13C0B0C5&0&48: Accton EN1207D Series PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter #2
```

Choose a piece of the string that identifies the device, and verify it is unique:

```
c:\>devcon find *VEN_1113     
PCI\VEN_1113&DEV_1211&SUBSYS_12111113&REV_10\3&13C0B0C5&0&48: Accton EN1207D Ser     
ies PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter #2     
1 matching device(s) found.
```

Make sure that "VEN_1113" means a single network card. 
devcon disable *VEN_1113

**Enable/disable the device**

```
devcon disable *VEN_1113      
devcon enable *VEN_1113
```

This allows me to enable/disable my network card (and therefore my internet connection) from the command line.

Comment: I have tried your example but it is no use.                                              `C:\Users>devcon find  =net "*DEV_8168*"
    PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_368217AA&REV_07\07000000684CE00000: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
    1 matching device(s) found.'`
                                                                                                                                               
    `C:\Users\zhilu1234>devcon disable "*DEV_8168*"
    PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_368217AA&REV_07\07000000684CE00000: Disable failed
    No devices disabled.`

Comment: Why the apostrophes and ending star? You wrote: devcon disable "*DEV_8168*"

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded another devcon by following [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/i-downloaded-devcon-on-my-win-7-64-bit-computer/77d28162-2cf3-41cb-818e-5ac0d68303b6), which solved the problem!

- Download the “Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 7.1.0  from Microsoft:    http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11800
- Download http://7-zip.org/
- Mount the WDK ISO
- Double click WDK\setuptools_x64fre.cab
- Copy _devcon.exe_00000 to a temp folder
- Rename _devcon.exe_00000 to devcon.exe
- Move devcon.exe to C:\windows\system32